# How to spy on multiple class/object methods with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

Is there a shorter way to spy on object methods than the following?

```js
describe('blah blah', () => {
    let localStorageSetSpy, localStorageGetSpy;

    beforeEach(() => {
        localStorageGetSpy = spyOn(window.localStorage, 'getItem');
        localStorageSetSpy = spyOn(window.localStorage, 'setItem');
    });

    it('yada yada', () => {
        // blah blah
    })
})
```

It would be nice if I could spy on the getter and setter as part of the same object. I tried reassigning `window.localStorage` to `jasmine.createSpyObj(...)` but got complaints about it being `readonly`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to interact with one object in your test, maybe you can do this

```
describe('blah blah', () => {
    const localStorageSpy = { getItem: undefined, setItem: undefined };

    beforeEach(() => {
        localStorageSpy.getItem = spyOn(window.localStorage, 'getItem');
        localStorageSpy.setItem = spyOn(window.localStorage, 'setItem');
    });

    it('yada yada', () => {
        localStorageSpy.getItem.mockReturnValue(...)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use some methods or functions to wrap around your window.localStorage operations. For example `store()` (which calls getItem) and `retrieve()` (which calls setItem).

Some benefits:

1. You will be able to spy on and mock said functions very easily.
2. In the future, you will be able to change the behaviour of these functions without having to care about what is done inside as long as the prototypes of `store()` and `retrieve()` stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('blah blah', () => {
    const localStorageSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('localStorage',['getItem','setItem']) // Jasmine automatically create a spy for you

    beforeEach(() => {

    });

    it('yada yada', () => {
        localStorageSpy.getItem = (() => { return mockReturnValue(...) }) // Do your test here. 
    })
})
```

Maybe you can try this. Jasmine createSpyObj will create spy for as well. However, for localStorage it is good that you come out with a mock implmentation.